# How to add multiple users using signalR with websocket connection in JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, signalr

We tried to open a websocket connection a SignalR instance, by connecting a SignalR hub, and then trying to perform a login on that websocket connection. Attempted to do this for a number of users/sessions at the same time i.e. executing with 50 user sessions via Jmeter and only 2 users/sessions was used and logged in the SignalR log.

Breakdown for multiple sessions(minimum 50)

- Connect to SignalR using a websocket connection
- Perform a login call on that websocket connection to a custom endpoint on the hub connection
- Maintaim that connection for the duration of the test(s) for each session
- Perform a logoff on the connection after the test have run
- Disconnect the websocket connection"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question can be comprehensively answered in its current form.

If you see only 2 users in logs you need to figure out what happened to other 48.

1. First of all check [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles), maybe you will be able to figure out something from response codes and/or messages
2. Second you can [temporarily enable storing request and response data](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter) so you can trace the full end-to-end flow for failing requests
3. And last but not the least you can [enable debug logging](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for the plugin you're using and inspect jmeter.log file for any suspicious entries